# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren' (Beautiful Soup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I'm attempting to use Beautiful Soup to build a dictionary containing tags for a number of different blog post ids.

I first wrote a function to handle one post ID:

```
def tags(id_):
        r = h.unescape(requests.get('https://example.com/category/'+id_).text)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
        return  {"id": id_, "tags": [tag.text for tag in soup.find("ul",{"class":\
        "tags"}).findChildren("a")]}
```

..and I get what I am expecting:

```
tags('a123')
{'id': 'a123', 'tags': [u'food and drink', u'beer', u'sonoma county']}
```

I modified the function to loop through a list of post IDs, such as:

```
postids = ['a123', 'b456', 'c789']
tags_dict = {}
def tags_list(postids):
    for id_ in postids:    
        r = h.unescape(requests.get('https://example.com/category/'+id_).text)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
        tags_dict['id'] = id_
        tags_dict['tags'] = [tag.text for tag in soup.find('ul',{'class':\
        "tags"}).findChildren('a')]
```

When I run `tags_list(postids)`, I'm getting:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren'`

...and I'm not sure why. Any thoughts on how to fix? Or is there a better way to approach altogether?

*EDIT:* Below is the final version of the function I ended up using. I wanted a list rather than a dictionary, so I made that change too.

```
postids = ['a123', 'b456', 'c789']
def tags_list(postids):
    tags_data = []
    for id_ in postids:    
        r = h.unescape(requests.get('https://example.com/category/'+id_).text)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
        data = {}
        data['postid'] = id_
        data['tags'] = [child.text
                     for tag in [soup.find('ul',{'class': "tags"})]
                     if tag
                     for child in tag.findChildren('a')]
        tags_data.append(data)
    return tags_data
```

Here's a sample output:

```
[{'postid': 'a123', 'tags': [u'food and drink', u'beer', u'sonoma']},
 {'postid': 'b456', 'tags': [u'travel', u'road trips', u'camping']},
 {'postid': 'c789', 'tags': [u'cooking', u'grilling', u'steak']}]
```

Comment: I couldn't get whole situation,  but it seems that `id_` at line after `for id_ in postids:  ` is impacting `tags_dict['tags'] = [tag.text for tag in soup.find('ul',{'class':\
        "tags"}).findChildren('a')]`.Because it might be possible that `https://example.com/category/b456` doesn't have attribute `ul`

Comment: Thanks @Muhammadimran, I think you're spot-on. Working through it, getting closer--I'll add notes on my progress in the comments on the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find('ul',{'class': "tags"})` is returning `None`.

If you want to use this in a list comprehension you need to filter out values which are `None` before using them.

There's a trick where you put the value in a list so you can filter it:

```
tags_dict['tags'] = [child.text
                     for tag in [soup.find('ul',{'class': "tags"})]
                     if tag
                     for child in tag.findChildren('a')]
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! I made that modification and was getting: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tag' referenced before assignment`, so I changed course a bit, ditching the list comprehension for an if statement that checks for the presence of 'ul'. 

`if soup.find('ul',{'class': "tags"}) != None:        
            for tag in soup.find('ul',{'class': "tags"}).findChildren('a'):        
                tags_dict['tags'] = tag.text`

I can run error-free, _but_ the resulting dict contains an entry only for the *last* id in my postids list. I think I am close so will be sure to update once I solve.

Comment: Success! Thanks Peter, working as expected for me. Updated the initial post with the code I ended up using.